# Scrapy > How to sort and filter the data extracted by the crawler in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, scrapy

I'm learning to use Scrapy to retrieve a forum page and send it to my email after sorting the data. The forum uses a hidden token based authentication so I learned to use the Formrequest function with a token. After that I manage to sort the data in a dictionary. All that part works well.

The crawler I'm building to upgrade my Scrapy skills is based on the http://quotes.toscrape.com/ website for more simplicity.

Here is my Scrapy script at today's date:

```
class QuotesSpider(InitSpider):
    name = 'quotes'
    result = []
    login_page = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/login'
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/love/']

    def init_request(self):
        return scrapy.Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

    def login(self, response):
        print()
        print(response.url)
        print()
        token = response.xpath('//*[@name="csrf_token"]/@value').extract_first()
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                         formdata={'csrf_token': token,
                                                   'username': 'test',
                                                   'password': 'test'},
                                         callback=self.login_page_response)

    def login_page_response(self, response):
        print()
        print('login page ', response.url)
        print()
        return self.initialized()

    def parse(self, response):
        print()
        print('start url ', response.url)
        print()
        for quote_path in response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'quote')]"):
            #print(str(quote_path))
            quote = {}
            quote['posttitle'] = quote_path.xpath("span[contains(@class, 'text')]/text()").get()
            quote['postauthor'] = quote_path.xpath("span/small[contains(@class, 'author')]/text()").get()
            quote['posturl'] = quote_path.xpath("span//a[1]/@href").get()
            quote['posttags'] = quote_path.xpath("div/a[contains(@class, 'tag')]/text()").getall()
            self.result.append(quote)
            '''
            yield {
               'posttitle': quote.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'text')]/text()").getall(),
               'postauthor': quote.xpath("//small[contains(@class, 'author')]/text()").getall(),
               'posturl': quote.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'quote')]//span//a[1]/@href").getall(),
               'posttags': quote.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'tag')]/text()").getall(),
            }
            '''

        next_page = response.xpath("//li[contains(@class, 'next')]//a/@href").get()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)

    def closed(self, reason):
        print(str(self.result))
```

The next step is to manage to sort the data stored in my dictionary. I want to learn how to filter info, how to keep for example only the entries that have the **friendship** tag in the **posttags** list of my extraction, remove everything else from the extracted data and print the result.
Can someone show me how?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to filter entries you don't want is to have an if statement checking if the "posttag" (for example) exists before appending it to the list (or yielding it as a item)

There are more advanced ways to do it like using [ItemLoaders and processors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) or even item [pipelines](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html).

I'm not sure what you meant by "sort the data in the dictionary" though.

Comment: As I explain at the beginning of my post, my final goal is to crawl a web forum. I need to filtrer out some elements of the crawl every time the script recovers data. It's a shame I cannot post here the result of the scrap to show you what I want to do. Thank you anyway for the help.